# Javascript object undefined when passed to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have two functions that are called one after another. Both try to check the length of an array object. (`obj`) 
so a snippet of my html file:

```
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'http://localhost:30232/Request',
       data: JSON.stringify(myjson),
       contentType: "application/json",
       success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           var x = responseData;
           clearResultsTable();
           $("#Results").show();
           createResultsTable(x);
           createGraph(x);
           $("#Results").trigger("click");
       },
       error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           var x = responseData;
           $("#sres").text(x.Amount);
       }
   });
```

However in the console I am getting this: 
[Undefined Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ5N9.png)

How come I am OK checking the length of obj in the first function call. but not the second one? And if it is undefined how come the debugger can see all the elements inside obj in the second function?

Javascript:

```
function createResultsTable(obj) {
    var counter = 0
    var arrlen = obj.length;
    var sym = $("#inSymbol").val();

    while (counter < arrlen) {
        $("#ResultsTable").append("<tr class='dataRow'><td>" + obj[counter].Month + "</td><td>" + sym + obj[counter].Capital + "</td><td>" + sym + obj[counter].Interest + "</td><td>" + sym + obj[counter].Total + "</td><td>" + sym + obj[counter].OverpaymentAmount + "</td></tr>")
        counter++
    }
}

function createGraph(obj) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var counter = 0

    data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Capital');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Interest');

    while (counter < obj.length) {
        data.addRows([
            [obj[counter].Month, obj[counter].Capital, obj[counter].Interest]
        ]);
        counter++
    }

    var options = {
        title: 'Interest/Capital by Month',
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartArea'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Where does `responseData` come from?

Comment: So don't post an image of your code, but add the code in your question, so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: responseData is the result of an AJAX POST

Comment: Which part in your code is giving undefined? I don't even see `obj` in your code (sorry, I don't look at images for code).

Comment: Exception is being thrown at: `while (counter < obj.length)`

Comment: there's no `obj` defined in you code. no wonder `obj.length` throws exception

Comment: try to store obj.length on temp var arrlen = obj.length; on the same way you did on createResultsTable, just in case some of the functions in the loop are doing side effects...

Answer (score 0):

Have found that this was to do with the Callback function of the Google Charts Loader. Which was calling the function with no parameters.